# Linux MIPS box: ICMP (ping) works, but TCP does not - how to fix it?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, icmp, settings

I'm trying to set up MIPS Linux box network. Here is it's configuration:

```
~ # ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CC:5D:4E:FF:45:7F  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ce5d:4eff:feff:2178/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1333 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:107853 (105.3 KiB)  TX bytes:45385 (44.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:5 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:936 (936.0 B)  TX bytes:936 (936.0 B)

~ # route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8

~ # iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm can ping Internet resources by IP adderss:

```
~ # ping 8.8.8.8         
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=44 time=60.757 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 60.757/60.757/60.757 ms
```

But DNS doesn't works:

```
~ # ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
```

And even local HTTP resources are unavailable:

```
~ # wget http://192.168.0.1/
Connecting to 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (192.168.0.1): Connection timed out
```

TCP connections hungs at SYN_RECV/SYN_SENT state:

```
~ # netstat -n
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State         
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:80          192.168.0.3:44939       SYN_RECV    <-incoming TCP
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.2:40019       192.168.0.1:80          SYN_SENT    <-outgoing TCP
udp        0      0 192.168.0.2:42177       8.8.8.8:53              ESTABLISHED
```

What can be wrong?
Thank You.

Comment: grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: Hello, what's the result of:  

`cat /etc/hosts`    

`dig @8.8.8.8 google.com`    

`wget http://192.168.0.2/`    

`iptables -t nat -L`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dHsMUdY9